# Can we integrate Android Screens with React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing an application using react.i designed UI screens for my app using android studio. My question is can i use this screens in my React-native app? is there any possibility that using android screens as UI and coding part for my application using ReactNative?

Answer (score 0):

You can use React-Natvie along with native Android code in same project. But for your use, the simple answer is no. You can't use Android XML layout with React-native, because Android leverages the lucid nature of XML to develop view layouts, while React Native uses JSX, a coupler of business logic and UI.

Comment: Thanks for the info